# Determine if Google Maps API is using an invalid key during runtime

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to determine whether a valid Google maps API key is being used. Using an invalid key, we receive an error stating that the google API has been disabled. I'd like to capture that return, and determine whether or not to do our geocoding functions based on that return.

As it stands, when we save a record, we look to see if the address has been changed. If it has, we get the geocode of that address, and after the success/failure message has been passed back, we continue on with our processing before we save the record.

When the API is disabled, the code simply stops. Nothing is returned - no success or failure. At this point, our code stops as well as we rely on the return so we know where to go from there. We are not looking for a way to get around licensing, simply a way to determine whether the API is disabled at runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about geocoding on serverside or clientside ?

Comment: We do this:
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
Check the status and results, return to main function upon completion
});

Hope this helps

Comment: The above is used AFTER google has disabled the maps API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no implemented option to detect a disabled API.

Last year I've made a [**feature-request**](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6834) , but I don't think that something will happen.

two possible options(there may be more):

1. when you use a map usually the API first will try to create the map(some elements will be added to the map-container ). When the API will be disabled, these elements will be removed. So you may do something when this happens(e.g. set a variable that indicates the disabled-status):

   ```
    document.getElementById('map-canvas')//map-container
     .addEventListener ('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e){
         if(!this.children.length){
           alert('the API has been disabled');
           if(window.google && window.google.maps){
             window.google.maps.disabled=true;
           }
         }
       }, false);
   ```
2. override the `alert`-method to intercept the particular message:

   ```
   (function(f){
     window.alert=function(s){
       if(s.indexOf('Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.')
          ===0){

         if(window.google && window.google.maps){
           window.google.maps.disabled=true;
           alert('the API has been disabled');
           return;
         }
       }
       f(s);
     }
   })(window.alert)
   ```

In both cases you may later use the (custom)`disabled`-property of `google.maps` to check if the API has been disabled:

```
if(google.maps.disabled===true){
  //execute alternative code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well there's something i found in **[Web > Maps JavaScript API > Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors)** under title **"Listening for authentication errors"**

> If you want to programmatically detect an authentication failure (for
>   example to automatically send an beacon) you can prepare a callback
>   function. If the following global function is defined it will be
>   called when the authentication fails.

so you just need to define a global function:

```
function gm_authFailure() { /* Code */ };
```

Comment: Great find! Incredible that Google didn't bother to document this better.

Comment: I am sorry but does the `/* Code */` inside that function represent the alert message to user?

Comment: @user177196 Whatever you write there will be executed. You can implement whatever you want, including alert message, retry, connect to another map service, etc. It's up to you :)

Comment: So, even if we put a function like `gmapsdistance()` that essentially hits the Google Maps API again, it would still work under `function gm_authFailure()`?  Or we can also issue a message to an end-user like this: `print("Your API is invalid! Please check")`?

Comment: @Papak do you happen to know if the function `gm_authFailure()` works in R/Rstudio?

Comment: @user177196 no it won't work. You can't use the API when not authenticated

Comment: @user177196 No I have no idea about it