# How to verify a google maps api key in html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I have a rather standard Google Maps page, using my own API key. The page only does some marker additions by JS and presenting it in a text-box. If the key is invalid or expired or whatever, the following page is displayed.

[image]

That is fine, but then I would like to at lest tell the user why it is  wrong. The map is accessed by standard:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
<p><input type="text" "readonly" id="status" size=40></p>
...
```

However, I would like to check that the API key is working and valid, and tell the user if the key is OK or not in that text box.

How can I do that?

PS. The problem with using a `callback` function in the `src=`, is that it returns regardless what is the API status, but not actually the status itself. [Here](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/07/02/identifying-when-google-maps-successfully-authenticates-your-api-key/) is a kludge solution of this.

---

**EDIT**: I found an answer in the obscurely and [poorly documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors) callback function, `gm_authFailure()`, and solved my question with:

```
function gm_authFailure() { 
    let apiError = "No or invalid API key!"
    document.getElementById('status').value = apiError; 
};
```

You don't even need to specify this callback in your URL, it will use it anyway!

Comment: Have you found a way to get the specific error message details from within gm_authFailure function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```
function gm_authFailure() { alert('yo'); };
```

In the global scope. Per this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors

Comment: Thanks! I just [found that too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46442822/1147688) a few minutes after I posted my question.