# How can I verify if my google maps API key is valid?

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I am trying to set up a new application to use a google map. I got the api key from another teammate who did the set up. I am wondering if there's a utility or some other way to check if the api key he gave me is valid. I am getting the following console error when running my application using the api key he gave me:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error- messages#no-api-keys xw.m @ util.js:219 (anonymous) @ js?key [key]&callback=initMap:122 Promise.then (async)(anonymous) @ js?key=[key]&callback=initMap:122
```

Comment: Well, if you run your application and such an error is thrown, it looks like you've either implemented the API call wrong or the key is invalid

Comment: Someone asked this question before. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100807/how-to-verify-a-google-maps-api-key-in-html-javascript)

Comment: The developer who set up this key is telling me that this key has been enabled and used in the past. He is skeptical when I tell him that the key is invalid. How could I confirm forsure that the key is invalid and its not something specific to my code/version/browser...

Answer (score 2):

There is a google chrome addon for that: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-platform-api/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne

Comment: How do i use that Addon ? I am Android dev and I would like to verify that I have valid API key.