# Google map is not working properly in android App

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-layout, kotlin

[image]

I want to use google maps in my android app.I created a android app and select google map activity.Then I paste my Api key in the .xml file.The activity code given below.

```
class maps : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

I have a login activity.I include this map layout in my login layout.
The code shows it add marker at sydney but when I Run my app....it shows a simple map without marker.
Please resolve...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onMapReady()` use something like,

```
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.8479731,150.6517908);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(sydney).zoom(19f).build();
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Also you need to add your `google map api key` under these files.
[image]

Comment: Please change these lat lng values to something like val sydney = LatLng(-33.8479731,150.6517908)

Comment: bro...tell me one thing..how to check weather my API key is valid or not

Comment: Never share your api key in public. if map is displaying then key should be fine.

Comment: map is displaying without key also

Comment: Can you create another key and check it, I cannot see map on this api key.
Also make sure you have used the same api key in complete project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222142/discussion-between-asad-khan-and-utkarsh-sharma).

Comment: I have enabled nearby places API. Is it valid for google_maps_key

Comment: If you need nearby places api then yes. but keep in mind it is paid service. Hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: I have enabled nearby places api then put key inside    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false"></string>...bt my map is not loading

Comment: did you followed the screenshot in answer?

Comment: Can you see what message are you getting in logcat? can you please share it here?

Comment: its too long...can't be shared here

Comment: bro..please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121139/google-map-initialization-issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you have meta-data of the map API KEY in your manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

?
Have a nice coding and day

Comment: Check if key is valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419000/how-can-i-verify-if-my-google-maps-api-key-is-valid

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key